# Шаблон toString в Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Почему Idea в шаблоне метода toString смешивает использование одинарных и двойных кавычек, прибегая к экранированию `'\''`, вместо того, что бы просто использовать двойные кавычки `"'"`?

```
public String toString() {
    return "MyClass{" +
        "name='" + name + '\'' +
        ", url='" + url + '\'' +
        ", port=" + port +
        ", validIps=" + Arrays.toString(validIps) +
        '}';
}
```

Это кажется неудобным. Есть какой-либо особый смысл?

Comment: `"name='"` - выражение типа String.  `'\''` - выражение типа сhar. char занимает существенно меньше места, чем строка длинной 1. ИМХО экономия на спичках.

Answer (score 2):

Так определено в Velocity-шаблоне для генерации кода `toString` по умолчанию.

При желании можно добавить свой шаблон.

- Вызвать соответствующий диалог <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> >> Generate `toString()`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Нажать кнопку `Settings` и перейти на вкладку `Templates` (по умолчанию используется шаблон `String concat(+)`):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Можно выбрать другой шаблон, например `StringJoiner`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тогда сгенерированный код будет выглядеть совершенно иначе:

```java
@Override
public String toString() {

    return new StringJoiner(", ", Foo.class.getSimpleName() + "[", "]")
            .add("bar='" + bar + "'")
            .add("baz=" + baz)
            .toString();
}
```

Или же можно скопировать существующий / создать собственный шаблон и использовать его для кодо-генерации.